# Wordpress не выводит ошибки

Tags: wordpress

wp-config.php

```
 define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
 define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );
```

в браузере:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И больше ничего. Вопрос: как узнать, в чем заключается ошибка?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё просто, добавьте в wp-config.php

```
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
```

И смотрите сообщения об ошибках в файле `debug.log`

Либо попробуйте добавить

```
@ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```